# Search Web Hover in HTML CSS

Tags: html, css, search, hover, search-box

I have my CSS and HTML like this:

```css
.expanding-search-form {
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;

}
.expanding-search-form .search-input {
 z-index: 2;
  height: 34px;
  width: 105px;
  float: left;
  transition: 250ms all ease-in-out;

}
.expanding-search-form .search-input:focus {
background-color: white;
  width: 490px;
  height: 40px;
  
}
```

```html
<form class="expanding-search-form">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1"><i class="material-icons">search</i></span>
       <input type="search" class="form-control search-input" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Daftar Saran" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
   </div>
</form>
```

And the result like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/XnAWb.png

If my pointer not placed in search box it will look like the image:

If my pointer placed in search box it will hovered and covered the menu.

And now my problem is how to make the search box look like hovered but without the pointer placed in search box and covered the menu, thanks.

Comment: What do you want the result to be? Your explanation is not clear

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean like this?

```css
.expanding-search-form {
display: inline-block;
width: auto;
}
.expanding-search-form .search-input {
z-index: 2;
height: 34px;
width: 105px;
float: left;
transition: 250ms all ease-in-out;
position : relative;
}
.expanding-search-form .search-input:focus {
background-color: white;
position: absolute;
width: 490px;
height: 40px;
}
.label{
position: relative;
z-index: 10;
float:left;
}
```

```html
<form class="expanding-search-form">
   <div class="input-group">
      <input type="search" class="form-control search-input" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Daftar Saran" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
      <div class="label"><span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1"><i class="material-icons">search</i></span>
         [enter image description here][1]
      </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

Comment: its make a search bar not expand

Comment: check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `:hover` pseudo-class as a new selector.

```css
.expanding-search-form {
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;

}
.expanding-search-form .search-input {
 z-index: 2;
  height: 34px;
  width: 105px;
  float: left;
  transition: 250ms all ease-in-out;

}
.expanding-search-form .search-input:focus,
.expanding-search-form .search-input:hover {
background-color: white;
  width: 490px;
  height: 40px;
  
}
```

```html
<form class="expanding-search-form">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1"><i class="material-icons">search</i></span>
       <input type="search" class="form-control search-input" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Daftar Saran" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
   </div>
</form>
```